# Gherkin {string} parameter Cucumber Expressions substitution in Cucumber 5.6.0 doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am trying to use Cucumber Expressions following the instructions here: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/

```
@Given("I connect to the {string} Database")
public void setDatabase(String databaseName) {
    String normalizedDatabaseName = databaseName.replaceAll("\\s", "") + "Database";
    DatabaseManager.setDatabaseConnection(normalizedDatabaseName);
    log.debug("Current Connection {}", normalizedDatabaseName);
}
```

When I run a step calling this:

```
Given I connect to the Local Host MySQL Database
```

I receive a message saying no step matches the above step and get a template output.

The code works if I use the following RegEx instead:

```
@Given("^I connect to the (.*?) Database$")
public void setDatabase(String databaseName) {
    String normalizedDatabaseName = databaseName.replaceAll("\\s", "") + "Database";
    DatabaseManager.setDatabaseConnection(normalizedDatabaseName);
    log.debug("Current Connection {}", normalizedDatabaseName);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in the first example, or does {string} not handle spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify string in your {} like {string} you have to put quotations around the variable in the feature file

so your feature file line should look something like this

```
Given I connect to the "Local Host MySQL" Database
```

The reason why the other worked is that you are using straight regex at that point and not cucumber expression and in regex, if you have a .* in parenthesis it is a capture group which matches anything

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. Just getting back to marking your answer. I ended up using the regular expression because I do not want quotes in my Cucumber to delineate strings. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using the below cucumber expression format, it differ with the programming languages

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try using " " around your parameter which you have written in the Feature File.
Also it will be better if you could share your Feature file here.